# android game always freezes only on samsung galaxy s2

Tags: android, libgdx, galaxy

our new game seems to be smooth on other phones but on **samsung gaxalxy s2** it always freezes and crashes. the application uses gdx lib. the issue seems to be connected with *the music*.
while the music is turned off from the code the gameplay is smooth, but after turning it on the whole series of crashes and freezes start.

Any solutions or advice on this ?
You can check the game here [Fish vs Pirates](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frismos.fvp)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can find help here : http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't have an SG2 device available for testing I assume, so you can figure out exactly the problem?

Comment: am downloading it atm, to try it with adb attached if this is the problem so you can see what the error maybe is... unless you just catch them silently?

Comment: went through 3 sublevels, no crash.. is it major level that has to be completed?
Need more info

Comment: @Yahor10 : thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @AndersMetnik : actually I have a galaxy s2, and there are no crashes. I think there are some differences between those devices. If you have a look at reviews the only ones who have crashes play  on Samsung Galaxy S2. 
I think the real freeze or crashes happen after the introduction levels, when there are more characters.

Comment: Okay, i'll play it later, maybe you should consider asking them what android version they are using (if you target more with your app).

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy S2 has a known audio bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17623

Supposedly using the `MediaPlayer` API instead of the `SoundPool` API is supposed to work-around the issue.  There are also reports that this is fixed in the ICS update.  (If you're not using the `SoundPool` API, then you're probably not seeing this particular issue.)